# Generating Rvs for a given PDf in python

Tags: python, statistics, probability

Two random variables  $X$ and $Y$ are distributed according to
\begin{align}
f_{XY}(x,y)=  \begin{cases}
    x+y & 0\leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \\
    0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I want to generate rvs of the given function using python. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: What does "rvs" stand for?

Comment: "Random values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) is straightforward to implement for this case.

```
import numpy as np


def rng_xpy(n, rng=None, chunk_size=1024):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(rng)
    rvs = []
    n_drawn = 0
    while n_drawn < n:
        # Draw numbers from U(0, 1) for x, y, and z
        # We draw numbers in chunks for efficiency
        x, y, z = rng.random((3, chunk_size))
        # Scale z to the maximum value of x+y
        z *= 2
        # We only want to use (x, y) values when z is less than x+y
        good_mask = z <= (x + y)
        xy = np.column_stack([x, y])[good_mask]
        rvs.append(xy)
        n_drawn += len(xy)
    # Because we draw in chunks, we probably drew too many.
    # Assemble the final array and trim it to the required number.
    xy = np.concatenate(rvs, axis=0)[:n]
    return xy
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer but I dont really understand this part:# Scale z to the maximum value of x+y. can you please elaborate

Comment: As described in the article, the proposal distribution that we sample `(x,y,z)` from needs to always be above the target distribution function. We are using a very simple proposal distribution that is just uniformly sampling from the bounding box defined by `f(x, y)`. The maximum value of `f(x,y)` is at  `f(1, 1)=1+1=2`, so we need to sample `z` from the `U(0,2)`. Sampling from `U(0,1)` using the `random()` method then multiplying by 2 is just a convenience. There are lots of other ways to write that code.